# How can I make delay for disconnection and reconnection process in BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-handler, android-timepicker

I have an issue with disconnection and connection process. Assume that I have a button which allow to disconnect the previous Bluetooth Low Energy device and connect with a new BLE device. Normally, the disconnection process take about 500ms->1second, thus, I have to make a delay process which aim to wait until disconnection process finishing. Then I will call the new connection process. This is my code

```
public void onClickButton( View v){
     //Disconnect previous 
     mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
     //Need to wait here...
     //Connect with new BLE
     mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
}
```

Do you think Timer, Handler, or Thread is best choice in my case? Thank all

This is my solution using timer

```
            final ProgressDialog  waitProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait ...", "Disconnecting ...", true);
            waitProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            new CountDownTimer(500,100) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    waitProgressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: Timer and handler are good. try it

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the wrong solution to try to estimate time since it depends on the connection parameters how long time it will take to disconnect since the device will wait for an acknowledgment that the peripheral has received the command.

Instead just wait for the onConnectionStateChange callback.